# How do I get information out of TextArea in Google App Script on the button click?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to make a simple script in Google App Script that takes information out of the Text Area and parses it upon button click. I was able to create text area, but I'm not able to extract the text out of it.

How do I get information out of TextArea in Google App Script on the button click?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the code that you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TextArea works as any other widget;

In the do Get function (or any other function where you create the widget) you have for example :

```
 var Mtext = app.createTextArea().setPixelSize(340,400).setName('Mtext').setId('Mtext');
```

And in the handler function :

```
  var bodytext = e.parameter.Mtext;
```

If ever you need to modify its content from an external function you can use :

```
var Mtext = app.getElementById('Mtext');
Mtext.setText('New text content...');
```