# General assistance in Google Apps scripting

Tags: google-apps-script

OK, I'm tired of searching for specific questions to help with a project, finding answers, changing my implementation which just adds more questions, realizing there's a better way to do things, etc.  So allow me to ask for general assistance, I will then do my best to research how to do it and ask further questions if needed.

- I'm writing a script to be used as a Gadget in a Google Site page
  (I'm more than willing to share this if anyone wants to take a look
  at it); right now I'm doing this just for me, but I want to write
  this to be easily used by others.
- This will list all user's Google Docs in a specified folder; when
  selecting the document from the list, the contents will be displayed
  for editing in another field.
- The user will be able to define certain lines, starting wit a period,
  to "mark" as chords that can be automatically transposed with the
  push of a button; that is to say, the user clicks a button and all
  A's go to A#, B to C, C to C# and so on, but only on the specified
  "Chord" lines.
- The user can then save this document back to the Google Docs for
  printing if needed.

I've got the layout mostly.  Some problems I'm coming across:

- Doing a `.find` apparently finds all documents that have the given string in the name and
  the contents.  The fix would be to put the document IDs in a Hidden, but it doesn't seem
  that a List returns the numbered item you clicked on, so how can I also get the ID
  that's stored somewhere else?
- I'd like the TextArea to be rich text for bolding and what-not; does
  Google Apps have a text editor (it'd be awesome if I could just put
  the Google Docs editor in a panel)?  RichTextArea has been
  deprecated, is there a replacement?
- To do the transposing, I was planning on just putting every character
  of the text area into an array, stepping through the array, when it
  sees a "\n" followed by a "." to flip a var "on", then changing any
  following characters, then if it sees another "\n" to turn the var
  "off"; is there a better way to do this?
- Or, is there way to add a script to a Google Document that would do
  the transposing (I know you can do macros for spreadsheets, but there
  doesn't really seem to be an equivalent for documents)?  That way I can
  just give out this macro and tell people to use on their existing document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you asked, yes, separate questions would be appropriate, because the combination of questions is very specialized, while the individual problems might be more general, and of use to more people. But let me take a stab at it anyway...

> [With the result of `find()`]... how can I also get the ID that's stored somewhere else?

[DocsList.find()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/docs-list/docs-list#find%28String%29) returns a list of [File objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/docs-list/file). Class File has a `getId()` method that returns the document ID you are used to seeing in Google Drive. To get the IDs of all your files:

```
var files = DocsList.getAllFiles();
for (var i in files) {
  Logger.log(files[i].getId());
}
```

You should also look at [DocsListDialog](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/docs-list-dialog) for creating a file picker that works on Google Drive.

> RichTextArea has been deprecated, is there a replacement?

No, not in apps-script. You've just got [TextArea](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/text-area). However, you may be able to embed a third-party rich text editor in your UI.

> To do the transposing, ... is there a better way to do this?

Change the TextArea.value into an array of lines, then manipulate those, without needing to manage an on/off state. See [How do I get information out of TextArea in Google App Script on the button click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12047576/how-do-i-get-information-out-of-textarea-in-google-app-script-on-the-button-clic) and [Javascript: Convert textarea into an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299604/javascript-convert-textarea-into-an-array).

```
// aTextArea contains user's input. Probably a Johnny Cash song.
var inputText = e.parameter.aTextArea;
var inputLines = inputText.split('\n');
for (var i in inputLines) {
  if (inputLines[i].charAt(0) == '.') {
    // Transpose
  }
}
// Put lines back together, if you wish
var outputText = inputLines.join('\n');
```

> ..is there way to add a script to a Google Document that would do the transposing...

Yes (capability extended to Docs and Forms since question was originally asked). <s>No, Spreadsheets are the only document type that can be a container for scripts at this time.</s>

Alternatively, you could employ a stand-alone script to operate directly on Docs! Perhaps with a script deployed as a [Web App](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_web_apps) that lets users pick the target music to transpose from documents on their Google Drive, and that then writes a new copy of the document, transposed?

Comment: OK, the DocsListDialog looks great, now I just have to figure out how to use it (I can get it display, now I have to configure it to show only documents in a certain, then how do I get the selected file to display in the TextArea).

Comment: I'm not at all familiar with what Google Apps Script can do with 3rd party stuff, can you point me in the right direction? Or, now you've got me thinking, can I make the GUI using Google sites, then have an Apps Script interact with elements?

So, would I have to do an array of arrays? Only put in the lines that start with .?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that 3rd party question. Yes you could have a Google Site be the container for your script, although I'm not expert on how it could interact with other elements in the site - try it, and ask any new questions that come up.

Comment: You had said I could embed a 3rd party rich text editor into my UI.  Since I'm building the UI in the script, I don't know how to do that.  I know I could build the UI just using widgets, gadgets and what-not in Google Sites (I know I can just add a text editor gadget), I could even add a button with a URL.  I just don't know how to run a script that would do the transposing, or if I could load a user's Google Doc into the editor.

Comment: I forgot to come back and update - I tried this and failed. Comments in [Issue 944](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=944) from googlers also say you "should" be able to embed 3rd party editors - but users note that the Caja compiler used by GAS break them. That was my experience as well.

Comment: Sorry, I just haven't had time to work on my project that much.  Since I didn't ask one specific question, the answers you've provided have pointed me in the right direction, thank you.